# Correct subpass dependency understanding

Tags: c++, 3d, vulkan

So, I am trying to understand Vulkan synchronization and subpass dependencies (heh)

I am following this doc here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples#swapchain-image-acquire-and-present

As I understand that's the most up to date?

Specifically trying to understand why the "Combined Graphics/Present Queue" subpass dependencies do what they do.

I found this awesome gist that explained it better than anything else I found: https://gist.github.com/chrisvarns/b4a5dbd1a09545948261d8c650070383

So using that gists style I tried to fill in what the steps on the second subpass mean.

Can anyone validate if the line by line comments of each parameter are correctly describing what it is doing?

```
    VkSubpassDependency dependencies[2] = {
        {
                // https://gist.github.com/chrisvarns/b4a5dbd1a09545948261d8c650070383
                // In subpass zero...
                .dstSubpass = 0,
                // ... at this pipeline stage ...
                .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
                // ... wait before performing these operations ...
                .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
                // ... until all operations of that type stop ...
                .srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_NONE_KHR,
                // ... at that same stages ...
                .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
                // ... occuring in submission order prior to vkCmdBeginRenderPass ...
                .srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
                // ... have completed execution.
                .dependencyFlags = 0,
        },
        {
                // ... In the external scope after the subpass ...
                .dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
                // ... before anything can occur with this pipeline stage ...
                .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
                // ... wait for all operations to stop ...
                .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_NONE_KHR,
                // ... of this type ...
                .srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
                // ... at this stage ...
                .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
                // ... in subpass 0 ...
                .srcSubpass = 0,
                // ... before it can execute and signal the semaphore rendering complete semaphore
                // set to VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT_KHR on vkQueueSubmit2KHR.
        },
};
```

Comment: The text for the first structure looks 95% sensible.  Give it's the same structure used twice, why didn't you just cut and paste the same descriptions from the first structure? The names change (subpass 0 vs external), but the underlying intent is the same.

Comment: I.e. "In subpass zero..." in the first case should become "In the external scope (i.e. after renderpass) ...". Why did "In" become "Before"?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the comments. So the first dependency is waiting on the color attachment writes to finish in the commands before the pass. Then second dependency is waiting for all color attachment writes to finish in the commands following the pass? I don't quite understand the purpose for that in the Combined Graphics/Present Queue example? What write operations would occur after the pass? Wouldn't the renderingCompleteSemaphore on the presentQueue provide all necessary memory separation and waiting?

Answer (score 1):

The first dependency says subpass 0 can't start fragment output until previous commands in the stream (before the start of the render pass) have completed their fragment output.

The second dependency says no external (i.e. the next render pass) can start its color attachment output until subpass 0 has completed it's attachment output.

The semaphore on the submit gets signalled when the submitted command buffer is complete (`vkQueueSubmit()`) or at least past the selected stages (`vkQueueSubmit2()` with a `stageMask`). You do need to make sure the frame is rendered before you notify the window system that it is available. Waiting for fragment attachment output is necessary somewhere. This could be enforced inside the submitted commands, or just using the semaphore itself.

> Wouldn't the `renderingCompleteSemaphore` on the `presentQueue` provide all necessary memory separation and waiting?

For the purposes of the swapchain signalling, yes. But it doesn't provide any guarantee that the graphics workload submits complete in order.

Vulkan commands are specified to *start* in command queue submission order, but can complete out of order. The dependencies in the main rendering command buffer ensure that the submits retire in-order, which is the desired behavior for frames.

Comment: Ok I see. So would that second dependency really only come to effect something when I either have multiple RenderPass's or multiple SubPass's in a command queue? The wording on the synchronization example made it sound like it was necessary for syncing with presentation?

Comment: Or wait, is it because the 'Combined Graphics/Present Queue' example has a signal semaphore set to VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT on the QueueSubmit2 and the second dependency is necessary to make that semaphore be signaled after the color_attachment stage has completed instead of at the start of the color_attachment state? I updated the comments in the original code with that assumption, is that correct?

Comment: Unless you are only rendering a single frame, you have multiple render passes in the command queue.

Comment: IIUC the subpass dependency has nothing to do with the semaphore signalling.

Comment: Look at the comment it says on the example here https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples#swapchain-image-acquire-and-present "/* In cases where the application signals the semaphore with
       VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT, or uses vkQueueSubmit,
       this second dependency could be omitted. */" That seems to really imply to me that the second dependency is related to the semaphore signaling, no?

Comment: Yes, but only indirectly. Updated answer text.